# Odd behavior with cart link in Spree

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, spree

Currently, I'm trying to add a cart link into a dropdown menu on my page.  The code is below:

```
   <ul>
    <a href="<%= cart_path %>">
      <li id="link-to-cart" data-hook>
        <%= link_to_cart %>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="<%= checkout_path %>">
      <li>
        Check Out
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
```

This works properly for the checkout path, but not for the cart.  The idea is to make the whole `<li>` the link to the proper location so that users have an easier time and don't have to specifically click on the text. What's rendered is shown in a screenshot below:

[image: inspect element view]

My current assumption is that an anchor tag cannot be encapsulated by another anchor tag, which results in what is shown.  However, that does not explain why there are three anchor tags to /cart in the resulting HTML.  How can I fix this behavior?  Or alternatively, can I retrieve cart information, such as number of items and subtotal through a different means other than `link_to_cart`?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at the link_to_cart implementation here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb#L15

Comment: That seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm still new to Ruby, so I have an additional question regarding this.  I tried referencing simple_current_order, but it's not in the scope of the .html.erb.  However, I am able to use spree_current_user in the same file.  What's the problem here?

Comment: Should I create my own app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb to override the default and include a new method that gives me the string I need? Or is there already a convention to do this?

Comment: You can extend the helper module (http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html) and overwrite the link_to_cart method. For the simple_current_order method, maybe you are using an old spree version?

Comment: So I looked at the code in my gem directory for spree and found that base_helper.rb actually uses `current_order` instead of `simple_current_order` and using that worked.  I guess they changed it in a recent version since I started this a couple months back (using 2.1.4).  If you want to rewrite your comments up as an answer, I'll accept it.  Else, I'll answer the question myself in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change how the cart is rendered you can overwrite the link_to_cart method into spree base_helper.rb. You can find instructions about how to extend that helper [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.5/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb#L15).